# How to animate an element bottom to top by using only jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I know I am asking a very common question, but I want to know if there is another way to `animate`  an `element` by using only jQuery? I have created an animation but I want to improve it and I don't know how I can. [Please check this fiddle to see the animation](http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/nmGRt/) or you can see it here: [walkoverapps](http://walkoverapps.com/).

I am just a little bit confused. Are there other ways to animate an element?

Comment: Your animation is nicely working, what do you want improve? JQuery `animation` has been designed by expert to do that, what would you like use another way to animate your rocket?

Comment: What do you mean by "improve"? Your animation is valid!  Do you want to add more animations? Otherwise, this is a case of [if it ain't broken, don't fix it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:If_it_ain't_broke,_don't_fix_it).

Comment: Are you trying to achieve using jQuery without help from jQuery UI animate function?

Comment: all of you is right but i want to do by doing path x or y axis how can i?

Comment: @Sarfaraz please give more details of what you want to do, maybe provide an example or describe how would you like it to be? every answer here is blindly trying to guess (without success) what you are asking for, and it's unlikely you'll find what you're looking for without more detail.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Please be clear.
If by improving you mean to make it smooth look into CSS3 transitions other people have posted below.
"using only jQuery" - .animate() is built into jQuery. No other dependencies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am guessing again that you want to get the coordinates of each step in that animation. jQuery animate function offers `step:function (number, tween)` which is called on every step in the animation. See demo for more details **http://jsfiddle.net/nmGRt/5/**

```
$('#rocket').delay(2000).animate({
    bottom: '600px'
}, {
    duration: 5000,
    complete: function () {},
    step: function (n, t) {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        $('#curVal')
            .text('X: ' + pos.left.toFixed(2) + ' Y: ' + pos.top.toFixed(2))
            .css({
            left: pos.left - 150,
            top: pos.top
        });
    }
});
```

---

I am guessing that you are trying this without `jQuery UI`. If you are targeting only for modern browsers then try below using CSS3. See [**Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility) table.

**JS:**

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#rocket').addClass('fire').css('bottom', 600);
}, 2000);
```

**CSS3:**

```
.fire {    
    -moz-transition: bottom 5s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 5s;
    -ms-transition: bottom 5s;
    -o-transition: bottom 5s;
    transition: bottom 5s;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nmGRt/2/

Additionally you can control the animation using some cool `cubic-bezier` function. See demo http://jsfiddle.net/nmGRt/3/embedded/result/

```
.fire {
-webkit-transition: all 5000ms cubic-bezier(0.880, 0.045, 0.750, 0.750);
   -moz-transition: all 5000ms cubic-bezier(0.880, 0.045, 0.750, 0.750);
    -ms-transition: all 5000ms cubic-bezier(0.880, 0.045, 0.750, 0.750);
     -o-transition: all 5000ms cubic-bezier(0.880, 0.045, 0.750, 0.750);
        transition: all 5000ms cubic-bezier(0.880, 0.045, 0.750, 0.750); /* custom */
}
```

You can generate this function from this site: http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

**Additional**

Quick playout with transform http://jsfiddle.net/nmGRt/4/embedded/result/

Comment: @Sarfaraz Accepting answer will not assign bounty to the answer. You may have to choose the answer that you want to give the bounty price. You should set the bounty amount right below the tick mark for accepting answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163513/bounty-expired-before-i-could-assign-it-to-answer-punish-me-not-my-answerer

Answer (score 5):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/naveendalmeida/JVMmE/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="pr" id="ani">
             <h3 id="rocket" style="bottom:50px"></h3>

            <div id="rocket-smoke"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function nav_animation(nav_obj, length, nav_intveral, direction) {
        var i = 0;
        var int = setInterval(function () {
            if (i < length) {
                    $(nav_obj).css(direction, i + "px");      
                i++;
            } else {
                window.clearInterval(int);
            }
        }, nav_intveral);
    }

    nav_animation('#rocket', 50, 1, 'bottom');
    nav_animation('#rocket', 100, 1, 'right');
    nav_animation('#rocket', 150, 1, 'bottom');
    nav_animation('#rocket', 200, 1, 'bottom');
    nav_animation('#rocket', 350, 1, 'right');
    setInterval("$('#rocket').css('-webkit-transform',' rotate(0deg)');",1700);
    nav_animation('#rocket', 400, 1, 'bottom');

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#rocket {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    right:91px;
    background:url(http://walkoverapps.com/landing-content/rct.png) no-repeat;
    width:68px;
    height:84px;
    z-index:20;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean this with the x and y axis, you can say the exact position like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rocket').delay(2000).animate({
        bottom:'+=600px',
        right:'-=200px'
    }, 5000,function(){});
});
```

you can also change "bottom" to "top" and "right" to "left" and "+=" to "-=" or just "-"

Comment: this was also good @caramba but am already doing this and if you give `top` position instead of `bottom` then animation not work proper in all browser i checked it when am making this animation thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Please try the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyshih/nEgjJ/49/)  attached.
you might need to improve this based on your requirement.

```
function animateCustom(cobj, clength, cintveral, cdirection) {

  var i = 0;

  var int = setInterval(function () {
    if (i < clength) {
        if (cdirection == 'y')
            $(cobj).css("bottom", i + "px");
        else if (cdirection == 'x')
            $(cobj).css("right", i + "px");            
        i++;
    } else {
        window.clearInterval(int);
    }
  }, cintveral);

}

animateCustom('#rocket', 100, 5, 'x');
animateCustom('#rocket', 200, 5, 'y');
```